# R: Recoding multiple variables based on common ifelse condition

Tags: r

Let's say my dataset contains 3 variables:

```
V1 V2 V3
1  a   b
1  c   g
2  e   c
3  d   a
4  w   e
```

Is there any way to simultaneously change the values of V2 and V3 to "x" and "y" when V1 equals 1? In other words, I want to avoid doing:

```
V2 = ifelse(V1==1, 'x', V2)
V3 = ifelse(V1==1, 'y', V3)
```

Comment: Your edit means that you have two different conditions for two different questions. Where is the commonality that you refer to in the question title? Also, since the question changed, I removed my answer to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it at the same time, but it still requires the ifelse statements so it does not become less code. You might as well just do them one at a time.

```
foo <- read.table(textConnection("V1 V2 V3
1  a   b
1  c   g
2  e   c
3  d   a
4  w   e"),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

transform(foo, V2 = ifelse(V1==1, 'x', V2), V3 = ifelse(V1==1, 'y', V3))
```

This returns:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  x  y
2  1  x  y
3  2  e  c
4  3  d  a
5  4  w  e
```

Comment: there's no need for the textConnection anymore.  You can use `text=` instead with read.table. Easiest solution +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any real way around testing the condition twice. A slight improvement might be

```
V2[V1 == 1] <- 'x'
V3[V1 == 1] <- 'y'
```

since this avoids the overhead of `ifelse` (specifically, it evaluates both the true and false results for *every* element in your test vector, and then splices the results together). Although you could do the test once with

```
for(i in seq_along(V1))
    if(V1[i] == 1) {
        V2[i] <- 'x'
        V3[i] <- 'y'
    }
```

but I'm guessing you don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but to modify Hong's answer, I'm guessing at

```
data[data$V1 ==1,] <- c(1,'x','y')
```

If that's not allowed, then replace the guts of Hong's `for` loop with essentially the same thing, i.e.

```
 data[data$V1==1,2:3] <- c('x','y')
```

(Thanks to  Wojciech Sobala comment for that improvement)

Comment: You can simplify to data[data$V1==1,2:3] <- c('x','y')

Comment: @Carl: This doesn't work. Remember that R will expand your new value into the dimensions required, first by rows and then by columns. This means the first row is assigned all x's, and the second row all y's.